# Can selecting an anonymous type be null?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq

I am going through a codereview and seeing something suspicious.

In the snippet below can **result** ever be NULL ?

```
        var result = (from number in _cmContext.SrvLocationWarmLine
                      where String.Compare(number.CurrentWarmLine, startingRange, StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0
                            && String.Compare(number.CurrentWarmLine, endingRange, StringComparison.Ordinal) <= 0
                      orderby number.CurrentWarmLine descending
                      select new { Number = number.CurrentWarmLine }).FirstOrDefault();
```

More generally: when applying FirstOrDefault against a *select*, can the result ever be null?

Comment: Of course it could be null. What is your problem whit this?

Comment: I'd assume if the `from` and `where` return zero results the `result` will be `null` or an exception will be thrown on the `orderby`

Comment: Yes, but for your case you would throw an exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when number is null and you are trying to access a member from it.

Comment: `result` will be null if there are no `number` elements matching the where clause.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Ordering an empty sequence doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't completely sure.

Comment: From the documentation : "The default value for reference and nullable types is null." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The `result` is `null` if the sequence is empty.
This happens if no `number` in `_cmContext.SrvLocationWarmLine` matches the condition in the `where` clause.

---

In general `FirstOrDefault()` (without a predicate argument) returns `null` for an empty sequence (no matter if that sequence was returned by a `select` or from something different).

The `FirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T>, Predicate<T>)` returns `null` if there is no element in the sequence matching the predicate.

---

Note that the `select` in the query syntax is translated into a `Select(...)` method call.

---

Edit: of course the above applies only if the type of the elements of the final sequence is a reference type. For value types the result would be `default(type)`, e.g. `0` for an `int`.

Comment: Would an exception not be thrown, I'm sure I've had an exception along the lines of: "Sequence contains no elements", when trying to do an order by on an empty sequence?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder no there would be no exception. Only `First()` (without `OrDefault`) throws on empty sequences, as well as `Single()`. And `SingleOrDefault()` throws if there are more than one (matching) element.

Comment: I know it wouldn't be thrown on `FirstOrDefault`, it was more about the `orderby` call but Servy has answered that on the question above.

Comment: There is one situation where I noticed that FirstOrDefault will not return null even if there are no matching records: from number in _cmContext.SrvLocationWarmLine where false select number.Id).FirstOrDefault() will return 0 since the return type is int.